# Android distZip with buildFlavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've started recently to use buildFlavors in Android Studio 2.3

Today I wanted to zip our aar lib for distribution, but the `distZip` tasks doesn't pick the `aar` up at all.

How should i configure the task?

I want to have a zip file that includes:

- Readme
- JavaDoc
- AAR

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'distribution'


...

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = archivesBaseName
        contents {
            from 'README.md'
            from 'build/libs'
            from 'build/docs'
            from 'outputs/aar'
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    publishNonDefault true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

     //
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            version version + "-dev"
          //
        }
        prod {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        ignore 'AllowBackup'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "/META-INF/LICENCE"
        exclude "/META-INF/LICENSE"
        exclude "/META-INF/LICENCE.txt"
        exclude "/META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
        exclude "/META-INF/NOTICE"
        exclude "/META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
        exclude "/LICENCE"
        exclude "/LICENCE.txt"
        exclude "/NOTICE"
        exclude "NOTICE.txt"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.6.7'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.6.7'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.6.7'

    androidTestCompile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.6.7'
    androidTestCompile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.6.7'
    androidTestCompile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.6.7'

    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:1.6.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.9.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:1.5.4'
}

distZip.dependsOn {
    tasks.findByName('generateProdReleaseJavadoc')
}

// create javadoc
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        classpath += project.files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files)
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }

}
```

Comment: would be great to atleast tell me whats wrong before downvoting my question

Comment: If i Understand it right you are creating a zip file like a release thing ? and want to include the aar file in it ?

Comment: @LazerBanana yes I want to include the aar in a zip with some docs etc

Comment: Fist of all is the aar file a product of the separate project ?

Comment: never done it before, its a theory for me but it might help you, if not feel free to edit my answer or tell and i will delete it if its not what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you configure the distribution like this?
This way you can expand your distribution and configure it as you wish.
Then the distZip included in the application plugin will pick it up.

Create a task to do what you need

```
task createDocs {
    def docs = file("$buildDir/docs")
    outputs.dir docs
    doLast {
        docs.mkdirs()
        new File(docs, "readme.txt").write("Read me!")
    }
}
```

Expand your distribution:

```
distributions {
    main {
        //in here you can use from() to bring what you wish, files,
        // artifacts from configurations, built projects etc
        contents {
            from(createDocs) {
                into "docs"
            }
            from ({project(':subproject.aar').aar}) {
                into "whatever"
            }
            from ("$buildDir/libs") //its always better to use a variable for the build directory imho
        }
    }
}
```

As well check the dependencies of the distZip task.
If it depends on the tasks that build your artifacts.

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/application_plugin.html